# Raspberry Pi overscan not stretching image

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, framebuffer, overscan

I have a composite car monitor like [this one](http://www.amazon.de/ePathChina%C2%AE-Video-Eingang-R%C3%BCckfahrkamera-Unterst%C3%BCtzung-Videoger%C3%A4te/dp/B00DBMIDTO/ref=sr_1_11?s=ce-de&ie=UTF8), but I can't seem to get overscan right on raspbian. By default overscan leaves borders and seems to display `4:3` stretched to `16:9`.

To be able to operate properly on this small screen I first set a bigger tty font and set the framebuffer to `720x408`, which is 1.5 times the size of the native monitor size. But now I can't adapt that to the borders.

Left and right fit and I figured out top and bottom offset should be `-32` and `-64` by setting the other to `100` each time, but both do not work. The image is positioned somewhere inbetween instead of stretched like it should. I have no idea why it would output a wrong ratio in the first place.

#### Thanks for your help!

PS: I already tried to get this done quickly with some automatic tool and without rebooting every time but it failed on me. If someone is interested, [this is my question to that matter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30687819/raspbian-command-for-changing-overscan-without-reboot).

UPDATE: I installed Kodi and found that there actually is a very handy calibration tool like I wished it. I set it up and didn't tried to use the values in the `/boot/config.txt` yet, but I want to show the values to you already:

```
left upper corner: 28, 30
right bottom corner: 25, 0
square ratio: 1:196
```